# how to insert table count value into db using codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I use this following code to print the count value from the db table now i need to insert this count value into the table please help me.

```
 $this->db->like($data);
    $this->db->from('student_table');
    $result= $this->db->count_all_results();
    echo "count:".$result;
```

This only display the count value

need to insert the count value to the db table

Comment: Make an UPDATE query?

Comment: $this->db->update('course_table', $result);

Answer (score 1):

its very simple, insert count value in database, as u have not mentioned that table name and attributes/fields in which you want to insert the count, i am putting up a general answer!

using **Insert** query

```
$this->db->like($data);
$this->db->from('student_table');
$result= $this->db->count_all_results();
$this->db->query("INSERT INTO tbl_name VALUES('$result')");
```

or if you want to count all rows in a table,

```
$result = $this->db->count_all('table_name');
```

Using **update** query

```
$this->db->where('id', $id);  // if particular value to update
$this->db->update('tblName', $result);
```